# What's the best solution for a Python programming environment?

Tags: python

I want to learn how to  program in Python and I've got plenty of tutorials/resources to do that however I don't have a solution as to where I'd test out my code and see the result.

For example: When I was learning Javascript I was using the Firefox Web Console and that would show me the result of my code.

I'd like to get something similar to this in Python. If it matters I'm running Windows 7 OS.

Thanks for any help and sorry for the basicness of the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python For my money, I'd say learn vim or emacs, they'll serve you well.

Comment: how is this not a dupe?

Comment: To avoid this turning into a "My favorite IDE is X " thread, just use the Interpreter built into python, by opening a command prompt and entering the path to python.exe, after that you should see some words and then `>>>` indicating its okay to start typing junk

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the Python interpreter inside of `cmd`. You can get to this by running your python executable in `cmd`

I find its a little better than the standalone interpreter, but its just a matter of opinion

Comment: This python interpreter should become your best friend. it is the bees knees, arms, legs and elbows.

Comment: Sorry for the newbieness here but do you mean the cmd prompt? I was unaware you could run Python in there. Interesting.

Comment: yes, command prompt. press windows+r and type in `cmd`, then type `python` and hit enter

Comment: Yep, I just type "cmd" into the search bar, so that how I refer to it

Comment: @TehTris, typing "python" will only work if he has his path variables setup

Comment: @user2925800 Yes. If you install Python windows you can run the interpreter (in the "cmd prompt").  Be sure that the Python exe is in the environment variables.

Comment: default win7 python installation doesnt do this automatically? its been so long since ive re-installed lol, sorry. `PATH_TO_PYTHON/python.exe` where PATH_TO_PYTHON is the folder you installed python at works instead of just `python` also, if paths arent set up :)

Comment: I believe there is a check box for it, but I can't remember

Answer (score 3):

I'm a pycharm fan myself:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

There's a fully capable free version.

Answer (score 1):

Try PyDev for development.  http://pydev.org/

> PyDev is a Python IDE for Eclipse, which may be used in Python, Jython and IronPython development

If you want to see the result of simple code, you could always use the Python command line.

Comment: Interesting, I'm definetely looking at around at this. Would I have to download anything else on top of this? Is this all I would need to be able to code Python? Thanks for the help.

Comment: installing python on your computer is all you need to get started. dont start messing with IDEs until you get a grasp on the language using a notepad and the python interpreter. IDEs are more for organizing enormous projects.

Comment: You can start by downloading Eclipse IDE (http://www.eclipse.org/).  Totally free, I use it to develop enterprise Java at my company.  You can then follow the instructions on the Pydev website on how to add the IDE to Eclipse.  Very straightforward instructions.

Comment: TehTris has a good point.  Unless you're building a project, you can start with the interpreter.

Comment: As an eclipse user who already had eclipse lying around I found PyDev to be a nice tool.  Outline mode and refactoring are all there like you would expect in a typical IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For a lightweight solution that is not really an IDE but a somewhat nicer interpreter, I recommend [Dreampie](http://www.dreampie.org/).

Answer (score 0):

PyScripter is an awesome Python IDE on Windows 7. Amongst other features, it allows you to run your Python code right within the IDE, just like on the cmd. 
 
Last *(but not least)*, who can forget IDLE. It is installed by default with any Python installation. Check your start menu; you should have it there. It has an interpreter for you to run your commands (or scripts) as well.

Hope this helps.